# ¿como mostrar datos de una tabla de base de datos en forma horizontal?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes tengo una tabla que registra:  fecha ! hora ! tipo, como se ve los datos estan registrados en forma vertical, es decir  en la primera fila seria algo asi:   2018-02-20  08:00:00 Inicio, segunda fila: 2018-02-20 !12:00:00 ! salida almuerzo, 3ra fila: 2018-02-20 ! 13:00:00 ! Llegada almuerzo, cuarta fila: 2018-02-20 ! 17:00 !salida  son muchos registros lo que quiero es que para la muestra en pantalla imprima algo asi:  Fecha ! Inicio ! salida almuerzo ! llegada almuerzo ! salida, en la fila de abajo salga los valores de fecha, debajo de inicio: 08:00:00, debajo de salida almuerzo: 12:00:00, debajo de Llegada almuerzo: 13:00:00, debajo de Salida 17:00:00, he probado  meter los datos en un array pero al recorrerlo con foreach(), sale todo en horizontal, busco que despues de salida, lo demas se escriba en una nueva fila y celdas

Comment: una pregunta: ¿Porque realizaste el registro de esa manera y de manera horizontal con 4 campos para ello por ejemplo?, así va a ser un infierno trabajar tu sistema, imagina una tabla de personal de esa manera que maneje los registros de 2000 o 3000 empleados de varias nominas, que va, te mato de pana. Deberia ser una fila por cada dia de registros, es decir, la clave primaria, el campo asociado a la persona, y los campos para las fechas y horas de entrada, salida almuerzo, entrada almjuerzo y salida final

Comment: Por cierto edita tu pregunta y agrega el código con que has intentado hacer la tarea, esta Genérica

Comment: Creo que no me entendiste:                                                       
 cedula            Fecha           Hora tipo
15825905 2018-02-20 09:00:00 Inicio
15825905 2018-02-20 13:00:00 Salida Almuerzo
15825905 2018-02-20 14:00:00 Llegada almuerzo
15825905 2018-02-20 18:00:00 Salida
15825905 2018-02-21 09:01:20 Inicio
15825905 2018-02-21 13:00:00 Salida Almuerzo
15825905 2018-02-21 14:00:00 Llegada almuerzo
15825905 2018-02-21 18:00:00 Salida
15825905 2018-02-22 09:00:03 Inicio
15825905 2018-02-22 13:00:00 Salida Almuerzo
15825905 2018-02-22 18:00:00 Salida

Comment: actualmente se ve asi, pero quiero que se muestre horizontal por cada empleado pero cuando llegue a salida, baje a otra celda cedula       fecha         inicio   salida almuerzo llegada almuerzo  salida
15825905     2018-02-20    09:00:00   13:00:00        14:00:00       18:00:00

Comment: claro que te entendi y por eso pregunte porque lo hiciste asi, pues lo veo como un error garrafal a la hora de querer hacer calculos y cualquier cosa con esa data, imagina esto: `fila1:cedula, fila2:fecha, fila3:tipo` lo vez lógico??? y si en vez de eso es: `fila 1->campo 1:cedula, campo2: entrada, campo3:sa_almuerzo, campo4: ent_almuerzo, campo5:salida`? tiene más lógica no? ahora en tu tabla como le harías para realizar una sumatoria del total de horas trabajadas por día para totalizar cuanto le van a pagar por el mes de trabajo? solo digo que tu tabla esta mal conceptualizada.

Comment: Ahora imagina que quieres filtrar los empleados que trabajaron en un determinado día del mes y sacarles la cuenta de su pago??? te serviría tu tabla?? creo que no! o sacar los promedios de tiempo de descanso del mes o de una jornada laboral del día entre todos los asistentes? y de seguro todos tus campos son de tipo varchar

Comment: Si publicas el código que tienes, podemos ayudarte a mejorarlo para realizar lo que buscas.